# Scrolling a DIV beneath an absolutely postitioned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a simple website that features a scrollable `div`. It works fine, but I also need an absolutely positioned `div` over the top of it -- and I still need it to scroll as if it wasn't there.

You can see a crude JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/41rawrks/

You can scroll the `div` with your mousewheel (or trackpad), but if the cursor goes over the other element (like below), you can't scroll anymore. Can I change this?

[image]

I imagine it's because the DOM no longer considers the cursor to be "over" the scrollable element once it hits the draggable one (even though the draggable element is absolutely positioned within the scrollable one).

What can I do?

I wouldn't have thought it was possible, but this site does it!

http://weareeli.dk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was a mixture of everything already mentioned.

`pointer-events: none` stopped the scroll getting stuck, but prevented the dragging option from working. The answer was to add `pointer-events: none` to the draggable element only when the column wasn't scrolling.

Monitoring the scroll event (without mouseclick) was easy, but I used the [jQuery debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) to detect when scrolling had *stopped*.

```
scrollers.scroll($.debounce( 250, function(){
    // Re-enable drag event
    $(this).next('.decadeHeader').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
}));
```

Simple solution and works a treat!

Answer (score 1):

If you switch the overflow from **#scrollDiv80s** to its parent **#wrapper80s** it works as you want:

```
#scrollDiv80s div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#wrapper80s, #wrapper90s, #wrapper00s {

    overflow-y: scroll; /* look at this */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* look at this */
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
.decadeHeader {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
}
.decadeHeader:hover {
    cursor: grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
#scrollDiv80s  {
    /* overflow from child removed */
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but it seems to throw off the calculations? :-/ http://jsfiddle.net/f57bbv3g/2/

Answer (score 1):

The .decadeHeader never scrolls, so it can pass the scroll event to the element underneath.
You need to add some children to .decadeHeader to get this to work. Something like:

Just include the script "_ezswipe.js" from https://github.com/TNT-RoX/android-swipe-shim in your html.

```
<script src="_ezswipe.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then add the class "_ezswipe" to

```
<div class="decadeHeader ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle _ezswipe">
```

Lastly add a little code to pass the event on.

```
function catchEvent(e) {
    document.querySelector('#scrollDiv80s').scrollTop += (e.detail.delta.y*-1);
}
var el = document.querySelector("._ezswipe");
el.addEventListener("swipeMove", catchEvent, true);
```

[Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/41rawrks/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/41rawrks/6/)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was following you until you said "Then in your JavaScript, center the #scrollsurface and and pass the scroll events to the element underneath." I have no idea how to pass a scroll event to the element beneath :-/

Comment: @Chuck It might need to be tweeked for your're instance maybe make the height 600%, this was designed to overcome a swipe problem on android devices. Runs well on firefox nightly.

Comment: I would also consider disabeling "pointer-events" as @iamdash says during the scroll, and renable when scroll is stopped, for a more fluid ux.

Comment: Wow. I really appreciate the effort, but your fiddle doesn't work... The scrolling still doesn't work if you start with the cursor over the DRAG ME box. Plus the ability to drag the DRAG ME box has stopped working. Appreciate all your efforts, though!

Comment: @Chuck what browser are you using? Works fine in firefox.

Comment: I'm using Chrome. I tested it in FF, as you suggested, and it does work... although it reverses the scroll direction when the cursor is over the drag bar :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62522/discussion-between-tnt-rox-and-chuck).

Answer (score 0):

You can either add pointer-events: none in CSS to the blocking element (no support in IE10 and below I think) or try adding e.preventDefault to a mouseenter/mouseover event on that element.